# How to assign process PK to a foreign key field in viewflow

Tags: django, view, viewflow

Hello im trying to build an esignature workflow using viewflow. Im doing so by linking my process model , to an esignature model where i keep the signatures by a foreign key. However , im facing this error.

```
Cannot assign "8": "ESignatureModel.paymentVoucherProcess" must be a "PaymentVoucherProcess" instance.
```

My flows.py

```
class Pipeline(Flow):
process_class = PaymentVoucherProcess

start = (
    flow.Start( 
        CreateProcessView,
        fields=["payment_code","bPBankAccount"]
    ).Permission(
        auto_create=True
    ).Next(this.approve)
)

approve = (
    flow.View(
        Signature,
        fields=["eSignatureModel"]
    ).Permission(
        auto_create=True
    ).Next(this.check_approve)
)

check_approve = (
    flow.If(lambda activation: activation.process.eSignatureModel)
    .Then(this.send)
    .Else(this.end)
)

send = (
    flow.Handler(
        this.send_hello_world_request
    ).Next(this.end)
)

end = flow.End()

def send_hello_world_request(self, activation):
    print(activation.process.payment_code)
```

Here is my models.py

```
class PaymentVoucherProcess(Process):
payment_code = models.CharField(max_length=250,default='sup')
bPBankAccount = models.ForeignKey('BPBankAccount', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
drop_status = models.CharField(
    null=True, max_length=3, default=None,
    choices=(('SCF', 'Successful'),
             ('ERR', 'Unsuccessful'))
)
remarks = models.TextField(null=True)


class ESignatureModel(JSignatureFieldsMixin):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    paymentVoucherProcess = models.ForeignKey('PaymentVoucherProcess', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here is my external custom view i used to insert the esignature aspect into my workflow

```
@flow_view
def Signature(request):
    form = SignatureForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        esig = ESignatureModel()
        signature = form.cleaned_data.get('signature')
        if signature:
            signature_picture = draw_signature(signature)
            signature_file_path = draw_signature(signature, as_file=True)
        pk = request.activation.process.pk
        #attempting to assign the foreign key field error occurs here
        esig.paymentVoucherProcess = pk
        form.save()
        request.activation.done()
        return redirect(get_next_task_url(request, request.activation.process))

    return render(request, 'cash/pipeline/jsig.html', {
        'form': form,
        'activation': request.activation
    })
```

Do let me know if you spot any of my mistaks

Comment: `esig.paymentVoucherProcess` is a foreign key. You need to either assign the related object `esig.paymentVoucherProcess = request.activation.process` or you can assign the id directly by adding "_id" `esig.paymentVoucherProcess_id = pk `

Comment: Hello @IainShelvington thanks for commenting again , however im faced with this error NOT NULL constraint failed: cash_esignaturemodel.paymentVoucherProcess_id

Comment: Hello @IainShelvington It seems like the pk has been resolved  , however im now getting a new error called " No transition from ASSIGNED" do you have a direction u can point me in?